# Creating a tab separated matrix with placeholders from a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix

I have a set of 500 cells and another set of about 12 genes. I also have a dictionary of dictionaries that contains the cell mapping to the gene, and the gene mapping to the count. I would like to structure this information into a matrix where we have cells as column names and genes as row names. Each cell by gene cell would contain the count number. If there is no count number for that specific cell, then fill it with a zero placeholder

Here is a toy example. Say you are given this data:

```
cells = set(['cell_1', 'cell_2'])
genes = set(['gene_a', 'gene_b', 'gene_c', 'gene_d', 'gene_e', 'gene_f'])
test_data = {'cell_2': {'gene_c': 13, 'gene_f': 6}, 
             'cell_1': {'gene_a': 12, 'gene_c': 2}}
```

We want to create a tab separated table like so:

```
            cell_1| cell_2
    -------|------|-------
    gene_a | 12   | 0
    gene_b | 0    | 0
    gene_c | 2    | 13
    gene_d | 0    | 0
    gene_e | 0    | 0
    gene_f | 0    | 6
```

The ultimate goal here is to write out this matrix in a tab separated format. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that outputs a tab seperated file:

```
cells = ['cell_1', 'cell_2']
genes = ['gene_a', 'gene_b', 'gene_c', 'gene_d', 'gene_e', 'gene_f']
test_data = {'cell_2': {'gene_c': 13, 'gene_f': 6}, 
             'cell_1': {'gene_a': 12, 'gene_c': 2}}
with open("genes.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write("name")
    for cell in cells:
        f.write("\t")
        f.write(cell)
    for gene in genes:
        f.write("\n")
        f.write(gene)
        for cell in cells:
            f.write("\t")
            if cell in test_data and gene in test_data[cell]:
                val = test_data[cell][gene]
            else:
                val = 0 # this could be considered an error
            f.write(str(val))
```

The file looks like this:

```
name    cell_1  cell_2
gene_a  12  0
gene_b  0   0
gene_c  2   13
gene_d  0   0
gene_e  0   0
gene_f  0   6
```

I left the cells and genes as lists instead of sets, to maintain their order. There's no efficiency difference with either of lists or sets so if you have them as sets already that would be fine too.

I output zero for any cells/genes that had no data, you may prefer to change that to a blank or raise an error.

Answer (score 0):

A pythonistic way would use list comprehensions. Furthermore, splitting the process in small steps makes it easy to read and maintain.

```
def make_matrix(genes, cells, data):
    return [[data[cell].get(gene, 0) for cell in sorted(cells)] for gene in sorted(genes)]

def add_headers(row_headers, column_headers, matrix):
    annotated_matrix = [[header] + row for header, row in zip(sorted(row_headers), matrix)]
    return [[""] + list(column_headers)] + annotated_matrix

def format_matrix(matrix):
    return '\n'.join(['\t'.join([str(item) for item in row]) for row in matrix])

print(format_matrix(add_headers(genes, cells, make_matrix(genes, cells, test_data))))
```

And [proof it works](http://ideone.com/nX7vAd).